# model forms fiels not displayed in views in django

Tags: python, django

The problem is that the first_name, last_name and email fields are not displayed in browser. The command prompt is showing no error and server is running smoothly.
I cant figure out whats the problem.Here is my code.I am using django 1.11 and python 3.6

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class signup(models.Model):
first_name=models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
last_name=models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
email=models.EmailField()
timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import signup

class sign_up_form(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = signup

      fields='__all__'
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from .forms import sign_up_form
# Create your views here.
def home(request):

   form = sign_up_form()
   return render(request,'signup.html',)
```

## signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<h1>join now</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}


   <input type="submit">
 </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you omitted to include your form in the template context, inside the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) method (note that the default `context` parameter is `None`).

```
def home(request):
    form = sign_up_form()
    return render(request,'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Also, as per [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), please name your classes as CamelCase (`SignUpForm` for your form, `SignUp` for your model etc.).